# How can I fix the issue the "Hash join code support issue" in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I found that GridDB FDW does not operate correctly. Could you please help me to fix it? I have a scenario as below which

```
set local min_parallel_table_scan_size = 0;
set local parallel_setup_cost = 0;
-- Extract bucket and batch counts from an explain analyze plan.  In
-- general we can't make assertions about how many batches (or
-- buckets) will be required because it can vary, but we can in some
-- special cases and we can check for growth.
create or replace function find_hash(node json)
returns json language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
  x json;
  child json;
begin
  if node->>'Node Type' = 'Hash' then
    return node;
  else
    for child in select json_array_elements(node->'Plans')
    loop
      x := find_hash(child);
      if x is not null then
        return x;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return null;
  end if;
end;
$$;
create or replace function hash_join_batches(query text)
returns table (original int, final int) language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
  whole_plan json;
  hash_node json;
begin
  for whole_plan in
    execute 'explain (analyze, format ''json'') ' || query
  loop
    hash_node := find_hash(json_extract_path(whole_plan, '0', 'Plan'));
    original := hash_node->>'Original Hash Batches';
    final := hash_node->>'Hash Batches';
    return next;
  end loop;
end;
$$;`
```

The `hash_join_batches` function does not operate correctly because the merge join algorithm is selected by the query `select count(*) from simple r join simple s using (id);` instead of the hash join algorithm.
After I tried `SET ENABLE_MERGEJOIN TO off`, hash join algorithm is selected, but issue still exist.